# x86 Assembly language and booting

Tags: assembly, x86

This question is related to the MIT Course Operating Systems Engineering (6.828).
In its very first lab boot-loader is introduced. It says that boot-loaders have to reside into the first sector of the bootable device, which is 512 bytes for hard-disks. The boot-loader which they have, has two source files boot.S and main.c, which is assembled into the binary boot.out.
From what I understand, this should be the binary stored in the first sector (bootable sector) of the hard-disk. But when I used the linux command "du -sh boot.out" to check its size, it came out to be 8kB. Shouldn't it be 512 bytes.
Further, they have also given a boot.asm which is a disassembly of the .text section of boot.out (ELF format). This file has sequence of assembly commands with addresses next to them where they are stored. A small portion of the file is shown below:

```
obj/boot/boot.out:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00007c00 <start>:
.set CR0_PE_ON,      0x1         # protected mode enable flag

 .globl start
 start:
.code16                     # Assemble for 16-bit mode
 cli                         # Disable interrupts
 7c00:  fa                      cli    
 cld                         # String operations increment
 7c01:  fc                      cld    

 # Set up the important data segment registers (DS, ES, SS).
 xorw    %ax,%ax             # Segment number zero
 7c02:  31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
```

This file contains address in 512 byte range. Why then the binary boot.out taking so much memory? Is it that only the .text section of the ELF gets loaded into the memory?

Comment: I haven't seen the `boot.S` file used in your course. Look at its contents -- does it use BIOS routine calls to read in the rest of `boot.out` into memory from the disk?

Comment: I think boot.out is the binary version of the file boot.S which is stored in memory in ELF format. So what you said should not be the case.

Comment: Probably the assembler is the first stage in the bootsector, the C file is the second stage (kernel loader). On BSD that was classically about 8k, so that would match.

Answer (score 0):

I think if your boot.out file in elf format so it is not boot-loader I think it must be booted with grub boot-loader.
First GRUB:

> GRUB stands for GRand Unified Bootloader and is a bootloader and the reference implementation of the Multiboot Specification. GRUB can boot any Multiboot-compliant OS (e.g. Hurd, among others), however it can also boot some non-Multiboot-compliant OSes, e.g. Windows, via a chain-loading function, and some others via special support, e.g. Linux. mbchk can be used to determine if a file is Multiboot-compliant.

and as says in following document it can load your elf, .. kernel for you :

> GRUB takes away all the complexities out of trying to boot your OS by doing it for you. GRUB can handle a variety of filesystems: from MS-DOS FAT systems over Linux ext2fs (Second Extended File System) to BSD FFS, and can load kernels in various binary formats, including "generic" ELF, FreeBSD a.out, flat binary, and "generic" executables (any file with a valid Multiboot header).

and other option is:
first your boot-loader 512's bytes loaded into memory and then it load other pieces as it needed. I think Linux 0.11 uses this option for loading and booting. you can see it source [here](https://github.com/yuanxinyu/Linux-0.11)

*please note that for use of second way your kernel must be in flat binary format*

**for more information in os development and ... see [OSDev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page).**

Answer (score 0):

Your "boot.out" looks like it's using the Elf file format. You need a flat binary file format instead. This means that you either need to convince the linker to use flat binary instead of elf for the output, or you need to use a tool (e.g. "objcopy") to convert from Elf into flat binary.

*Note 1: For hard disks the first 512 bytes of the disk are typically reserved for the MBR and partition table, and the boot loader goes in the first sector of a partition and not the first sector of the disk.*

*Note 2: Under no circumstances does it ever make any sense to switch to protected mode in the first 512 bytes of a boot loader.*

Comment: Brendan, the first 512 bytes of a partitioned disk *is* the MBR. The first 446 bytes of the MBR are bootstrap code which is run as the first stage of booting from the disk. The partition table, which is part of the MBR, starts from the 467th byte.

Comment: @AlexD: In general (by convention) the MBR has nothing to do with any OS's boot code and is a general purpose (OS neutral) thing. For simple cases the MBR can be simple (e.g. find the active partition and chain-load), and for more complicated cases (dual boot) the MBR might be a fancy thing that lets the user choose which OS to boot.

Comment: ..of course like all good things, it gets ruined by people who don't understand and want to cut corners at the expense of others